# How can I prove that $B_0 \cup X$ generates $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let be $T:V \rightarrow W$ a linear transformation with $dim(Ker(T))<\infty$ and $dim(Im(T))<\infty$. Let be $B_0$ a basis of $Ker(T)$. Let be $Y \subset W$ a basis of $Im(T)$, and we have that for every $y_i \in Y$ there exists $x_i \in X \subset V$ such that $T(x_i)=y_i$.

I have to prove that $B_{0} \cup X$ is a basis of $V$. I've already proved that $B_0 \cup X$ is linearly independent but I don't know how to prove that $B_0 \cup X$ generates $V$, can you help me please? I would be very greatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T(x) =0$, then $x\in Ker(T) $ so $x\in span(B_0)$.
If $T(x) \neq 0$, then $$T(x) = \sum c_iy_i = \sum c_iT(x_i) = T\left(\sum c_ix_i\right) $$

This implies that $x - \sum c_ix_i$ is in the Kernel, which makes $$x - \sum c_ix_i \in span(B_0) \implies x \in span(B_0\cup X) $$

Comment: At the beginning we have to add that $x \in V$, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, for sure.

Comment: @FormerMath Note that there is no need to do it by cases: for every $x \in V$ there are 
scalars $c_i$ such that $T(x) = \sum_i c_iy_i$, which implies $x-\sum_i c_ix_i \in \ker T \subseteq  \operatorname{span}(B_0 \cup X)$, and then $x \in \operatorname{span}(B_0 \cup X)$.